# Angular 9, http Delete method by ID not working

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm trying to delete data from a fake API service using the delete method

Here it's my code
component.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
        <li *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index" class="list-group-item">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="deletePost(post)">Delete</button>
            {{i+1}} {{post.title}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and component.ts

```
  //  deletePost(post){
  //    this.service.deletePost(4000)
  //     .subscribe((response: any) => {
  //       console.log("inside Response")
  //       console.log(response.status)
  //       let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
  //       this.posts.splice(index, 1);
  //     }, (error) => {
  //       console.log("inside error")
  //       if(error.status === 404){
  //         alert('this post has already deleted.')
  //       }
  //       else{
  //         alert('An error');
  //         console.log(error)
  //       }

  //     })
  //  }

  deletePost(post){
    this.service.deletePost(post.id)
     .subscribe(
       (response) => {
        let index = this.posts.indexOf(post);
        this.posts.splice(index, 1);
     }, (error) => {
      console.log(error)
     })
  }
```

service.ts

```
private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  deletePost(id): Observable<any>{
    console.log(this.url + '/' + id);
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }
  handleError(error){
    return throwError(error.message || "An Error");
  }
```

the total number of posts on the fake API is 100
when I tried to use a static number like 101 or more instead of `post.id`
it didn't raise an error and give me back a 200 status code in the network tab and still deletes the element of the page although it's not it id

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with your fake API. You're service.ts should error with a 500 if the id doesn't exist. Maybe try removing the `.pipe(catchError())`

Comment: it returns an empty object like this {} and the status code is 204

Comment: I was following some tutorial and it works with him using the commented part in component.ts